# html not coming properly in outlook

Tags: c#, html, outlook, gmail

Html emails are not displaying properly in outlook, but are working fine in gmail. What should I do?

There is a design break in outlook..

Here is the html code:

```
strEmailBody = strEmailBody + " <table id=\"table_banner\" cellspacing=\"10\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"100%\" align=\"left\" bgcolor=\"#09355A\" border=\"0\"  style=\"padding-bottom: 8px;    margin-bottom: 12px;\">";
strEmailBody = strEmailBody + "<tr><td >";

strEmailBody = strEmailBody + "<span style=\"font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 52px;color:white;\"><strong>Family</strong>Connect<sup style=\"font-size: 20px;\">®</sup></span>";
//strEmailBody = strEmailBody + "<span style=\"FONT-SIZE: 10PX;FONT-WEIGHT: BOLD;vertical-align: text-top; bottom: 1ex;color:white;position:relative; bottom: 2.3em;\">TM</span>";
strEmailBody = strEmailBody + " <p style=\"border-bottom: 3px solid #ee7701;border-bottom-color: #ee7701;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 4px;\"></p> ";

strEmailBody = strEmailBody + "<span style=\"font-size: 15px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:white;\">For parents of children with visual impairments </span>";
strEmailBody = strEmailBody + "</td></tr>";
strEmailBody = strEmailBody + "</table>";

strEmailBody = strEmailBody + "<br><br>A new Blog Entry has been posted on the \"" + strBlogName + "\":  <br><br>";


strEmailBody = strEmailBody + " <br><br><p>You are receiving this message because you signed up to receive e-mail alerts whenever there is new activity on this blog. You can ";
strEmailBody = strEmailBody + "the " + strUnsubscribeLink + "unsubscribe" + "</a>" + "  at any time. ";
strEmailBody = strEmailBody + " This email was delivered to you by the American Foundation for the Blind. Replies to this email address cannot be answered. For questions/concerns email us at <a href=\"mailto:afbweb@afb.net\">afbweb@afb.net</a>.</p>";
```

[image: Email in Outlook]

above is the photo of outlook.

[image: Email in Gmail]

no.2 image for gmail..

What should I do???

Comment: Copy your strEmailBody value to html validator(take the value with debuging). Also show how you are creating the email

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to send the Email?
If you are using MailMessage, do you set IsBodyHtml to true?

```
MailMessage mm = md.CreateMailMessage(mailTo, ld, new Control());
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: This sounds like your prob: https://help.aweber.com/hc/en-us/articles/204030726-Why-Doesn-t-My-HTML-Message-Display-Correctly-in-Outlook-